# android sql server data

Tags: android, sql, http

how popular android applications deal with database servers (sql) does they insert and remove data from the db directly using JDBC driver (using username and password of the db) or they go through http requests to transmit and receive data and than the server scripts deal with the operations ! and thank you !

Answer (score 1):

If Apps would connect directly with a database server, the username and password would have to be stored in the application, which is a major security flaw.

Private data should not be stored in an application since the code can be easily reversed.

"Popular" apps would use a middleware to communicate with the database, like a REST API.

You can start by checking the Firebase Database which is secure and easy to use:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write

Comment: thank you for the helpful informations !! i ll check the link of the firebase !!

Answer (score 0):

it all depends on your needs. App can manage a local sqlite database for example to which you will insert or get data from the app directly (you can use jdbc here). However, if you app is connected to a server, the app must not query the database directly (for security reasons). It must go through your server scripts (Web services) in order to write / read data to the database.

Comment: thank you so much that was so helpful !  no i totally got the idea how to build my app !!